# Check if entity reference field (user) contains current user

Tags: entities

I have a node page of **Project** content type which contains a multiselect enitity reference field of user type called **field_team**. I also have a block created by my custom module which is displayed at Project type pages only. What i'm trying to achieve is to do smth like this:

```
if ($current_node->field_team contains $current_user->uid) {
  $output = 'some_specific_content'; 
} else {
  $output = 'you are not a team member of this project';
}
```

How can I check if currently viewed node contains current user in its reference field?
Will be very thankful for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following code:

```
global $user;

$team_members = array();
foreach ($current_node->field_team['und'] as $team) {
  $team_members[] = $team['target_id'];
}

if (in_array($user->uid, $team_members)) {
  $output = 'some_specific_content'; 
} else {
  $output = 'you are not a team member of this project';
}
```

Comment: Replaced uid by target_id